# Missing something from the requirements for the Analytical Badge?

Tags: support, badges

I thought I had gone through the entire FAQ and clicked on all the links as I read through them, but no badge shows up under my programmers profile.

Here is the what the badge reads: **Visited every section of the FAQ**

Does that mean I have to include all the links to the linked pages? Does it take some time to show up? I'm not sure what I've missed here.

Comment: How long ago did you do this? Badges do take some time to be awarded.

Comment: Yesterday sometime.  I went through it twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check that you've clicked on all the section links - including the first.

The badge *should* turn up a few minutes after you've done this.

Comment: That worked, I wasn't expanding all the section links, thanks!